# Serialize table tr data?

Tags: jquery, serialization, html-table

I'm serializing my form using :

```
formVals = $('#formID').serialize();
```

But I also have a table that I'd like to serialize and add it to `formVals` Can that be done? I've tried :

```
$('#tableName').find('tr').each(function(){
    formVals = $(this).text().serialize();
})
```

But that results in

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text(...).serialize is not a function

What I want to do is take the text from each `tr` and add it as a new entry to `formVals` along with the exiting date. Is there way to do this?

UPDATE

A row looks like this :

```
<tr id="12354-515-asd">
<td>Today</td>
<td>0000</td>
<td>Monday</td>
<td>2345</td>
</tr>
```

The expected values to be added to formVals is:
`12354-515-asd=Today0000Monday2345`

Comment: What is the querystring output you want to have? What key value should each `tr` use?

Comment: Current output from the form is `key=value&key=value` etc. I'd like to add to this as tr id = all row text values etc.

eg: `12354-515-asd=Today0000Monday2345&145155-545-BFE=Now1230Wednesday2100`

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense. Could you add a small sample of your table HTML to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenate each parameter to `formVals`.

```
formVals = $("#formID").serialize();
$('#tableName').find('tr').each(function(){
    formVals += '&' + this.id + '=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, that seems to do exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text(...).serialize is not a function" is because serialize() is not a function applicable to a "tr" or "td" element (you cannot do this):

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form controls, such as , , and : $( "input,
>   textarea, select" ).serialize();

If you wish to append this data you need to build a string by fetching the ID of the table row, and then iterating through each `<td>` element (appending the data within) -- See Barmar's answer for a solid example.