# How to access cell data from iframe Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-sheets

I'm trying to pull two specific numbers from a chart on a [football website](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/buf/2018.htm) (Column PF, Row "Team Stats" and "Opp. Stats") and import them to my website as a JavaScript variable which I can do math, etc. with. My solution thus far since I don't want to get into anything too crazy has been use the IMPORTHTML function in Google Sheets, create a table, then export that bit of the spreadsheet using the "publish to web" feature which condenses it into an iframe.

I've tried using object properties of the iframe to access it including a getElementbyId dot property among others.

```
<h1>
        <script>
            var iframe = document.getElementById("data");
            var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document;
            //.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
            document.write(elmnt);

        window.parent.document.getElementById('data')
        </script>
    </h1>
```

I was hoping for an output of the correct number but am getting [object HTMLDocument] or undefined depending on the properties I'm trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) ?

Using the api, you would use this simple command :

```
var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range);
var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
```

but the [setup](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) is a bit heavy

If you dont want to you can still [serialize table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358656/serialize-table-tr-data/40359634).

Here is the work of [John Dyer](http://johndyer.name/html-table-to-json/) :

```
function tableToJson(table) { 
  var data = []; // first row needs to be headers var headers = []; 
  for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,''); 
  } 
  // go through cells 
  for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) { 
    var tableRow = table.rows[i]; var rowData = {}; 
    for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) { 
      rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML; 
    } data.push(rowData); 
  } 
  return data; 
}
```

the you'll can use data[column][row] to get the cell data;

In my opinion using the API is the best option in this specific case.

Comment: I went down the route of APIs and its a little too complicated for me. I'm hoping to do this in Vanilla JS and plan on only really transferring data from one tab on my home computer to another (though automated and lots of it on a recurring basis hence the need for this). Since I can load in iframes without too much difficulty it seemed like a better route to go down but I'm struggling with all three of these. Thanks so much for your help